# Why does this JavaScript code return an error?

Tags: javascript

I know in JavaScript only function declarations are hoisted, which means it should print 30 after running the function sum.

However it says diff is not defined, shouldn't it be hoisted?

```js
sum(10, 20);
diff(10, 20);
    
function sum(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}
    
let diff = function(x, y) {
  return x - y;
}
```

Comment: because you call the function before you have defined it

Comment: To understand this, you need to understand the JavaScript hoisting mechanism. Basically, hoisting rewrites the code before executing, such that `sum` and `diff` are declared at the top, then `sum` is defined, your calls are made, _then_ `diff` is defined (that definition is left after the calls because you used `let`). So you're calling before you define.

Answer (score 1):

It's because as you said, only function declarations are hoisted, not function expressions (assigning a nameless function to a variable). Following code works:

```js
sum(10, 20);
diff(10, 20);
    
function sum(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}
    
function diff(x, y) {
  return x - y;
}
```

To declare `diff` the way you did, you must lift it to the top of your code:

```js
let diff = function(x, y) {
  return x - y;
} 

sum(10, 20);
diff(10, 20);
    
function sum(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, let and const are hoisted but you cannot access them before the actual declaration is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: `let` and `const` _declarations_ are hoisted, but their _definitions_ are left in place. Same basic idea as what you're saying, but I wanted to be more precise.

Answer (score 0):

You are accessing the function before you initialize it.

So this should work,

```js
let diff = function(x, y) {
  return x - y;
} 

function sum(x, y) {
  return x + y;
}

console.log(sum(10, 20));
console.log(diff(10, 20));
```

Answer (score 0):

**let diff** will hoist but at the moment when function **diff(10, 20);** will be called variable diff will not jet be defined with the function.
Google this topic **function declaration vs function expression**

Answer (score 0):

Because `Function Expressions` are not hoisted like `Function Declarations`

> Function expressions in JavaScript are
> not hoisted, unlike function declarations. You can't use function
> expressions before you create them:

```
console.log(notHoisted) // undefined
//  even though the variable name is hoisted, the definition isn't. so it's undefined.
notHoisted(); // TypeError: notHoisted is not a function

var notHoisted = function() {
   console.log('bar');
};
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#function_expression_hoisting

---

You will need to use a `Function Declaration` if you want it to be hoisted.